# Google custom search API specifiy image dimension

Tags: c#, api, google-custom-search, dimension, google-image-search

I am doing a google custom search request for image.

My request is below

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=key&cx=cx&q=hello&searchType=image&alt=json&start=1
```

I know I can specify the image size i.e.

> [huge, icon, large, medium, small, xlarge, xxlarge]

But what I want to specify image search should be greater than 600x600.

On google page I saws by specify dimension it was adding like

> &tbs=isz:lt,islt:qsvga

So I tried to do this like

> https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=key&cx=cx&q=hello&searchType=image&alt=json&start=1&tbs=isz:lt,islt:qsvga

But no luck.

**Obviously I can filter within results returned by API, but that is not beneficial as it will reduce the count of image returned.**

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have made something similar using JS that lets you search google images with a custom height and width. If you just want to use this instead you can find it [here](https://soaringgecko.github.io/8K-image-search/). If you want to make this yourself though... I wouldn't blame you because programming is fun. (at least it is for me)

Comment: What do you mean by it has no results?

Comment: Well I'm glad I could help